# ValueError: generator already executing

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, generator, auto-keras

The following generator is throwing an exception.

How can I resolve this issue?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import autokeras as ak

DATA_COLUMN_COUNT = 12 
LABEL_COLUMN_INDEX = 2
FEATURE_START_INDEX = 3
NUM_OF_FEATURES = DATA_COLUMN_COUNT - FEATURE_START_INDEX
NUM_OF_CLASSES = 3          
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 111
MAX_TRIALS = 10
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 200
VALIDATION_STEPS = 50

def load_data(file_path):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep='\s+', usecols=range(0, DATA_COLUMN_COUNT))
    print("Sample data with usecols and correct separator:")
    print(data.head())
    label_conversion = {'H': 0, 'E': 1, 'C': 2}
    y = data.iloc[:, LABEL_COLUMN_INDEX].map(label_conversion)
    y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=len(label_conversion))
    x = data.iloc[:, FEATURE_START_INDEX:].to_numpy()
    return x, y

def data_generator(file_paths, batch_size, num_classes):
    while True:
        for file_path in file_paths:
            x, y = load_data(file_path)
            # Remove the redundant to_categorical call
            # y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes)
            for i in range(0, len(x), batch_size):
                end = i + batch_size
                batch_x = x[i:end]
                batch_y = y[i:end]
                if batch_x.shape[0] < batch_size:
                    padding = batch_size - batch_x.shape[0]
                    batch_x = np.pad(batch_x, ((0, padding), (0, 0)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
                    # Ensure batch_y has the correct number of dimensions before padding
                    batch_y = np.pad(batch_y, ((0, padding), (0, 0)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
                yield batch_x, batch_y

def create_generators(folder_path, batch_size, num_classes, validation_split=0.2):
    files = [os.path.join(folder_path, f) for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.dat')]
    train_files, validation_files = train_test_split(files, test_size=validation_split)
    train_gen = data_generator(train_files, batch_size, num_classes)
    validation_gen = data_generator(validation_files, batch_size, num_classes)
    return train_gen, validation_gen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_folder = r'/home/my_username/my_project_v2_original_data'
    train_gen, val_gen = create_generators(data_folder, BATCH_SIZE, NUM_OF_CLASSES)
    
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: train_gen,
        output_signature=(
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, NUM_OF_FEATURES), dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, NUM_OF_CLASSES), dtype=tf.float32)
        )
    )

    validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: val_gen,
        output_signature=(
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, NUM_OF_FEATURES), dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, NUM_OF_CLASSES), dtype=tf.float32)
        )
    )

    clf = ak.StructuredDataClassifier(max_trials=MAX_TRIALS, overwrite=True, num_classes=NUM_OF_CLASSES)

    # Fit the model
    clf.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, validation_data=validation_dataset, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS)
    best_hps = clf.tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]
    print(best_hps)
    model = clf.export_model()
    # Save the model
    model.save("cnn_autokeras_by_chunk_without_ohe")
    # Evaluate the model
    evaluation = clf.evaluate(validation_dataset)
    print(evaluation)
```

```
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:/git/my_project_v2/my_project_v2/my_project_v2_autokeras/cnn_autokeras_by_original_by_chunk.py
Using TensorFlow backend
2024-02-12 23:14:56.551477: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Sample data with usecols and correct separator:
   0    1  2      3       4       5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   0  SER  C  0.000   0.000   0.000   1   1   1   1   1   0
1   1  ASN  C  5.651   8.805   0.000   1   1   1   1   1   0
2   2  ALA  C  5.582   5.602   9.099   0   0   0   1   1   0
3   3  MET  C  5.756   7.791   7.902   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   4  ILE  E  6.853  10.406  11.253   0   0   0   0   0   0
Sample data with usecols and correct separator:
   0    1  2      3       4       5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   0  PRO  C  0.000   0.000   0.000   1   1   1   1   1   0
1   1  ILE  E  6.388  10.133   0.000   1   1   1   1   1   0
2   2  MET  E  7.090   9.464  12.018   0   0   0   0   1   0
3   3  LEU  E  6.281   9.841  12.931   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   4  ARG  E  6.628   5.599   9.306   0   0   0   0   0   0
2024-02-12 23:14:58.258253: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: generator already executing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: generator already executing


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git\my_project_v2\my_project_v2\my_project_v2_autokeras\cnn_autokeras_by_original_by_chunk.py", line 97, in <module>
2024-02-12 23:14:58.260762: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: generator already executing
Tr    aclf.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, validation_data=validation_dataset, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS)ce
back (most recent call last):

  File "  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\autokeras\tasks\structured_data.py", line 326, in fit
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: generator already executing


2024-02-12 23:14:58.263112: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: generator already executing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: generator already executing


2024-02-12 23:14:58.265071: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: generator already executing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: generator already executing


2024-02-12 23:14:58.266913: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: generator already executing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: generator already executing


2024-02-12 23:14:58.271889: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: generator already executing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: generator already executing


2024-02-12 23:14:58.274866: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: generator already executing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: generator already executing


    history = super().fit(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\autokeras\tasks\structured_data.py", line 139, in fit
    history = super().fit(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\autokeras\auto_model.py", line 283, in fit
    self._analyze_data(dataset)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\autokeras\auto_model.py", line 369, in _analyze_data
    for x, y in dataset:
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 809, in __next__
    return self._next_internal()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 772, in _next_internal
    ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 3055, in iterator_get_next
Sample data with usecols and correct separator:
   0    1  2      3       4       5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   0  MET  C  0.000   0.000   0.000   1   1   1   1   1   0
1   1  THR  C  7.281  10.424   0.000   1   1   1   1   1   0
2   2  PHE  C  6.626   8.966  12.663   0   0   0   0   1   0
3   3  GLU  C  6.220   9.739  12.658   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   4  LEU  E  6.748  10.167  12.863   0   0   0   0   0   0
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5888, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} ValueError: generator already executing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\from_generator_op.py", line 198, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ValueError: generator already executing


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name: 
2024-02-12 23:14:58.675970: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:108] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
2024-02-12 23:14:58.676507: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:108] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is it needed `while True`? Also, could you please share full reproducible code? A colab gist would be fine.

Comment: I think the problem is, you're passing a generator to a another generator wrapper.  The data_generator is already a generator and possibly can be passed to model.fit. If you can give plug-n-play code with some dummy data, it would be helpful to debug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) needs the generator function itself as its first parameter, not a instanciated generator object that you provided with e.g. `train_gen`.
The correct code would be (with the `args` parameters for the generator arguments):

```py
files = [os.path.join(folder_path, f) for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.dat')]
train_files, validation_files = train_test_split(files, test_size=validation_split)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    data_generator,
    args=(tf.constant(train_files), tf.constant(batch_size), tf.constant(num_classes))
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, NUM_OF_FEATURES), dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, NUM_OF_CLASSES), dtype=tf.float32)
    )
)
```

Also, I'd not batch the data inside the generator. `Dataset` has its own `.batch(size)` method for that, and also [`padded_batches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) for filling with e.g. zeros. Beware that I seldom worked with generators, so I'm not exactly sure about that. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators) is an example for a Datset from generator, which then gets batched and padded.

Comment: you probably meant `train_gen` instead of `data_generator` line 3

Comment: No, I didn't. If you look at the example in [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), the `generator` argument needs the generator function itself (`gen` in that example). `train_gen` is an instance of that generator (already created), not the generator function itself. `Dataset` will call the function with the arguments given in `args`, and create its own instance.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I would suggest removing the first line of code then.

Comment: Oh, you're right. That was the wrong line to copy, I wanted to add the train/test split line. Fixed it, and thanks!